# Simple GUI app for showing touchscreen activity / coordinates?

Tags: software-rec, testing, touch-screen

Per the title, I have a touchscreen system (raspberry-pi based) that I need to test/diagnose the touchscreen behaviour of and demonstrate functionality to a customer.

All I need is a simple GUI application that I can make fullscreen that will display the location of touch events - I'm sure such a thing must exist but so far the closest I've got is Xeyes which is neither accurate enough nor quite serious enough for the job at hand.

I know there's websites that do this but that's putting a whole layer or five of stuff in the way and part of the problem is we're seeing different touch behaviour in a browser compared to the desktop, so really need a native app to prove this.

So - recommendations please!